# Silverlight windows phone 8.1 FileOpenPicker for all files Continue not working

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, fileopenpicker, windows-phone-silverlight, all-files

i create **silverlight windows phone 8.1** project and i need to choose all kind of file from windows phone

i used FileOpenPicker for choose the file it redirect correctly and i can choose the file this is my code

> ```
>        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
>         openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
>         openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
>
>         openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
>         openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
> ```

And i follow [this msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642086(v=vs.105).aspx) for receiving select

In my case 
if i selecting file and come back to the app its every thing working
if i without select any file and come back using mobile hardware back button my app come to home screen. **but it need to stay file picker page**

my first page[image: First page]

[image: second page]

[image: Third page]

when i press mobile hardware back button in above screen the page redirect to my first page it need to stay in my second page

thanks

Comment: not quite sure what you want, but have you tried to tap into `protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)` ? Then you can decide what happens on the hardware backbutton.

Comment: JTIM when i press the back button in photo, phone page it should back in my second page (attach button page ) but now it redirect to first page. here back key press wont hit

Comment: You could then catch the navigation uri out of the page and save a variable, that you then compare upon the app is reactivated. In reactivation you then specify which page you should navigate to. It however seems odd that you do not navigate to sevond screen, thar would be normal behaviour. Have you set the application to tombstone when it is pushed to background?

Comment: JTIM, i done some little hack . in OnNavigatingFrom method please let me know i i did any wrong. please find my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer and avoid redirection

```
 bool reset;
        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {

            if(reset && e.uri.tostring().Equals("MainPage.xaml"))
             {
                e.Cancel = true;
                reset = false
             }


        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            reset = e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Reset;
        }
```

Comment: Seems fine, just be aware, that when the user now is inside the app and press backkey, he would probably exit the app. Since there are no navigations in the Navigation-stack. Just for your info :) I can't say if everything works, you would have to test that for your self :)